# Словарь и удаление значений

Tags: python-3.x

есть словарь `my_dict = {'даша': 2, 'петя': 1, 'коля': 1}`
Как сделать, если значение равно 1, то удалить и ключ и значение? Если это возможно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_dict = {key: value for key, value in my_dict.items() if value != 1}
# -> {'даша': 2}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
import json
from browser import document

@document["mybutton"].bind("click") 
def on_click(event):
    my_dict = json.loads(document["json"].text)
    print({key: value for key, value in my_dict.items() if value != 1})    
</script><label for="json">JSON ввод: </label><span id="json" contenteditable="true">{"даша": 2, "петя": 1, "коля": 1}</span> <button id="mybutton">Запустить</button></body>
```

Обратите внимание, что удаление во время итерации привело бы к ошибке:

```
#XXX BROKEN: DO NOT USE!!!
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if value == 1:
        del my_dict[key]
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Чтобы её избежать или многократно обходить словарь или копировать его пришлось бы, поэтому можно сразу dict comprehension использовать (первый пример кода в ответе), который новый словарь создаёт.